# How to call method of a unknown object

Tags: java

I want to do something different with java reflection. The program i written to add global listeners to java components when applets are opened from browser. An event fired and i get event source object. Here i don't know the actual class name that object referring to.

```
if(object.getClass.getName().contains("oracle.ewt.laf.basic.BasicTabBarUI$Menu"))
{
   // here we can invoke methods,fields,etc using reflection
}
```

I can call the methods of BasicTabBarUI$Menu class with reflection.

Suppose now i have the following lines with me in the above if block

```
LWMenuItem menuItem = (LWMenuItem)object;
menuItem.getLabel());
```

I don't want to specify LWMenuItem class name , instead i want to call its method getLabel(). If we know the class name , we can do as above. But how can we do same with reflection. How can we do casting in reflection?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do casting, except of the result of calling the method. Just use the object's `Class` object, which has a [`getMethod` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) that will return a [`Method` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) for the method you want, then invoke it:

```
Class cls = object.getClass();
Method getLabel = cls.getMethod("getLabel", null);
String label = (String)getLabel.invoke(object, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue working with the basic object when using the return value from `getLabel()`:

```
Method getLabelMethod = object.getClass().getMethod("getLabel");
Object menuItem = getLabelMethod.invoke(object);
menuItem.getClass().getMethod("getName").invoke(menuItem); // or whatever...
```